# How to compute the functional derivative of the following functional encountered in electrical impedance tomography?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

**Note**:

1. I have raised this question in [Mathematical stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4011899/how-to-compute-the-functional-derivative-of-the-following-functional-encountered) but it received no attention. That is why I proceed to here to ask this question. Please tell me if this is not appropriate, thank you.
2. For simplicity, I have ignored the integration variable in the text. One can assume that the usual measure for the set/boundary is used.

### Background

In the context of [*electrical impedance tomography*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2004.11.022), one encounters the following partial differential equation.

> Let $ \Omega $ be a bounded Lipschitz domain in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ with $C^1$ boundary $ \partial \Omega $ with outward normal $ n $. Assuming $ \Omega $ contains material with electrical conductivity $ q(x) $ satisfying $ q(x) \geq q_0 > 0 $. Then the electrical potential $ u(x) $ inside $ \Omega $ satisfies
> \begin{gather} \label{eqn:eitpde}
> - \nabla \cdot (q \nabla u) = 0 \text{ in } \Omega \tag{1} \\
> q \nabla u \cdot n = f \text{ on }\partial \Omega \tag{2} \label{eqn:eitbc}
> \end{gather}
> where $ f(x) $ is the applied current density on $ \partial \Omega $ satisfying $ \int_{\partial \Omega} f(x) \operatorname{d}\! x = 0 $.

The inverse problem is stated as

> Given the values of $ f $ and $ u $ on the boundary $ \partial \Omega $, recover the values of $ q $ in $ \Omega $.

In solving the inverse problem, one may define the following mismatching functional
\begin{equation} \tag{3} \label{eqn:mf}
F(q) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\partial \Omega} (u - m)^2 
\end{equation}
(The simplified version is stated here for easier discussion, for the complete mismatching functional, please refer to the above reference.) Then it remains to compute the gradient of $F$, now according to my understanding, the gradient of $F$ is the functional derivative, i.e. Gateaux derivative of $F$.

From the above reference, the gradient of $F$ is computed as
\begin{equation} \tag{4} \label{eqn:gradf}
\frac{\operatorname{d}\!F}{\operatorname{d}\!q} = - \nabla u \cdot \nabla z 
\end{equation}
where $ z $ satisfies
\begin{gather} \label{eq:avpde}
  - \nabla \cdot (q \nabla z) = 0 \text{ in }\Omega \tag{5} \\
  q \nabla z \cdot n = u - m \tag{6} \label{eq:avbc}
\end{gather}
with the constraint
\begin{equation} \tag{7} \label{eqn:zcons}
  \int_{\partial \Omega} z = 0.
\end{equation}

### My attempt

In attempt to compute the functional derivative, I have first assumed a perturbation in $ q $ by $ \epsilon \tilde{q} $ which induces a corresponding perturbation in $ u $ by $ \epsilon \tilde{u} $. The change in $F$, denoted by $ \delta F $ is then
\begin{equation} \tag{8} \label{eqn:Fturb}
  \delta F(q) = \epsilon \int_{\partial \Omega} \tilde{u}(u - m)  + O(\epsilon^2).
\end{equation}
But then, the perturbations $ \tilde{u} $ and $\tilde{q}$ are related by
\begin{equation} \tag{9} \label{eqn:uqturb}
  - \nabla \cdot [(q + \epsilon \tilde{q}) \nabla (u + \epsilon \tilde{u})] = 0
\end{equation}
which transforms to (with ignoring higher order terms)
\begin{equation} \tag{10} \label{eqn:uqturbfinal}
  - \epsilon [ \nabla \cdot (\tilde{q} \nabla u) + \nabla \cdot (q \nabla \tilde{u})] = 0
\end{equation}
Multiplying \eqref{eqn:uqturbfinal} by $ z $ and integrate over $ \Omega$, with applying Green's identity, yields

\begin{equation} \tag{11} \label{eqn:asqnew}
  \int_{\partial \Omega} z \tilde{q} \nabla u \cdot n - \int_\Omega \tilde q \nabla z \cdot \nabla u + \int_{\partial \Omega} q z \nabla \tilde u \cdot n -  \int_{\partial \Omega} q \tilde u \nabla z \cdot n -  \int_\Omega \tilde{u} \nabla \cdot ( q \nabla z ) = 0.
\end{equation}
So by adding \eqref{eqn:asqnew} to \eqref{eqn:Fturb}, one obtain
\begin{multline} \label{Fturbnew} \tag{12}
\delta F(q)/\epsilon =  \int_{\partial \Omega} \tilde{u}(u - m) + \int_{\partial \Omega} z \tilde{q} \nabla u \cdot n - \int_\Omega \tilde q \nabla z \cdot \nabla u \\ + \int_{\partial \Omega} q z \nabla \tilde u \cdot n -  \int_{\partial \Omega} q \tilde u \nabla z \cdot n -  \int_\Omega \tilde{u} \nabla \cdot ( q \nabla z ) + O(\epsilon^2).
\end{multline}
Now it is evident that if one assumes that $ \nabla u \cdot n $ is given, then $ \tilde q = 0 $ on $ \partial \Omega$ by \eqref{eqn:eitbc}. From the given gradient one also knows that the term $  \int_{\partial \Omega} q z \nabla \tilde u \cdot n $ should be zero, So that, if $ z $ indeed satisfies \eqref{eq:avpde} and \eqref{eq:avbc}, then \eqref{Fturbnew} becomes
\begin{equation} 
\delta F(q)/\epsilon =  - \int_\Omega \tilde q \nabla z \cdot \nabla u + O(\epsilon^2).
\end{equation}
So, one picks $ \tilde q = \nabla z \cdot \nabla u $ to ensure the functional decreases along the gradient direction.

My question would be:

> How do you know the term $ \int_{\partial \Omega} q z \nabla \tilde u \cdot n $ is zero?